# Power BI - Can I run multiple queries on Power BI desktop during importing? Is that a bad design?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I'm using Power BI to display a number of reports for my business.

For each report, I have a sql query and will use the 'Import Data' function to load the data for each report.

E.g

This is the query for the report data that I want to load and it will be e.g report 1 :

select *
from employee_name_and_salary
where salary<100;

I would like to store the data from each run of report 1 into a table so I can use it for historical data reporting of report 1.(I will do this for a number of reports ~100)

So in the import query I would like to use the following statement:

insert into report_history
select *
from employee_name_and_salary
where salary<100;

select *
from employee_name_and_salary
where salary<100
;

Please could you let me know if this ok? Will insert statement take space on the PBIX file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the `INSERT` in your database prior to pulling the data into the `.PBIX` i.e. create a stored procedure or something to handle that process. Once this has been set up you can just select * from that table in your `.PBIX`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is there a way I can do this without a stored procedure? I don't think I'll have access to create stored procedures.

Comment: @user7104603 Yes of course, you can just update the table using some SQL. Just do a google search for update in SQL https://www.zentut.com/sql-tutorial/sql-update/ this might be helpful